# adds values to input if url has two conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that adds values to two inputs if the url is date.html but now I would like to make it with two conditions.

Like so:
if date.html
and
if date2.html are in the url.

How would i do that?

```
var url = location.pathname;
    if (url.indexOf('date.html'))
    {
jQuery("input[id*='ctl00_ctl00_ctl00']").val('14/04/2011');
jQuery("input[id*='ctl00_ctl01_ctl00']").val('15/04/2011');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (url.indexOf('date.html') >= 0 || url.indexOf('date2.html') >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

The `>= 0` test is necessary because `indexOf()` returns `-1` if the string *isn't* found, and may even return `0` if the substring is right at the start [not that it would in a legal URL].

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want "date.html" and "date2.html" then you can do this:

```
if ((url.indexOf('date.html') >= 0) || (url.indexOf('date2.html') >= 0)) {
  //...
```

Or more concisely with a regular expression:

```
if (url.match(/date2?\.html/)) {
  //...
```

*However*, if you want to match "`date(*ANY NUMBER HERE*).html`" then try this:

```
if (url.match(/date\d*\.html/)) {
  //...
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work.i tested it with a date3.html and it adds values to the input in this file :(

Comment: Right, the last example matches any numbered date HTML file (e.g. "date1234.html").